# what happens when you declare the same object/variable more than once (newbie)

Tags: c++

what does something like this do?

```
static int i;

// wrapped in a big loop
void update_text()
{
    std::stringstream ss; // this gets called again and again
    ++i;
    ss << i;
    text = new_text(ss.str()); // text and new_text are defined elsewhere
    show_text(text); // so is this
}
```

does is create a new instance of ss in the stack with a new address and everything?  would it be smarter to use sprintf with a char array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each time the function is called, a new, local, instance of `std::stringstream ss` is pushed upon on the stack. At the end of the function, this instance is destroyed and popped off the stack.

At no point in time does the scope of function `update_text` have multiple variables in its scope with the identifier `ss`. So, within the scope of `update_text`, there is only one `ss` identifier.

A character array would make no difference. Each time the function is called, the char array, if statically allocated, will be pushed onto the stack and popped off at the end. If you use dynamic memory and dynamically allocate the character array, the `new` and `delete` statements would still be executed each time the function was called, and the pointer to this character array would still be pushed and popped off the stack. The `std::stringstream` is already handling the `new` and `delete` for you internally.

Declaring an object multiple times would look like this:

```
void Function()
{
    int x;
    int x;
}
```

This would cause compiler errors.

Be warned, this however, is valid:

```
void Function()
{
    int x;
    if(true)
    {
        int x;
    }
}
```

Because the two variables are of different scopes. The second `x` exists only within that `if` statement. As such, the compiler can infer that any reference to `x` after that declaration and within that scope refers to the second `x`. Note that the type doesn't matter, it's the identifier or "name" that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Small point: Your question isn't about declaring an object more then once, but encountering a position where an object is initialized more then once.

So to answer your real question: Yes it will create new instance of `ss` each time the function is called (although if it's called from the loop chances are that the address will actually be the same, but that really shouldn't matter to the programmer).

For your second question: Would it be smarter to use `sprintf` with a char array? Well if you are new to c++ the answer you should take from this is no, since `sprintf` is in a way more dangerous to use then `streams` (lack of typesafety, risk over overflows). The actual answer would be it depends. Use `sprintf` if you know what you are doing and the performance you get with using `stringstreams` isn't enough for your purposes (which should happen rarely). Furthermore note that you could reuses `stringstreams`, which reduces the overhead of creating new ones each time (which is significant for streaming a single `int`) you can also look at [`Boost.Lexical_Cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html) for this type of casting. According to their [the performance section of there documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/performance.html) it should be as fast as `sprintf` for things like converting `int` to `string` (haven't tested it myself, so no guarantees) without exposing the lack of typesafety (and risk of bufferoverflows) of `sprintf`. C++11 also has `std::to_string`, which does the conversion without giving up safety (however it's much less flexible then boost::lexical_cast`).

Comment: does it use new memory or space when a new instance of ss is created?

Comment: @john: a) why would you care? b) It will be put at a stackaddress corresponding to the stackaddress the function was called with, which can be the same as for earlier instances (but doesn't have to be). It will allocate it's internal buffers on the heap on creation , so the internal buffers will be allocated each time the function is called, however whether or not the memory system decides to give it the same chunk of memory or not is anyones guess. So it will get created each time, but it might reuse the memory (or not, who cares).